# How to switch WiFi from AP to ST mode on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system image built by another.
The WiFi is setup as Access Point.
I would like to attach the system to my Home WiFi system.
Where is this documented?

Checking environment:

1. cd /etc/netplan/ not found
2. cat /etc/network/interfaces

   ## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

   ## Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:

   source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
3. cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

   [main]
   plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

   [ifupdown]
   managed=false

   [device]
   wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

   [keyfile]
   unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlan0
4. ls /etc/ yields a long list of entries, none which seem to match the device I am working with.

Bottom line:

I was unable to resolve this on my own. The vendor of the device containting the Ubuntu image was able to provide a proceedure to allow me to switch the WiFi from AP to ST mode.

Seems like we would all be better off if network operations were standartized across all Operating Systems.

Thanks for all the helpful suggestions.

Comment: Is networking configured in Network Manager or netplan? `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: cd /etc/netplan/  not found

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and also: `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: "Seems like we would all be better off if network operations were standartized" They are standardized in Ubuntu. I think your problem is: "built by another." The previous owner has done some customizations that we don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Network Manager is set to ignore your wireless interface. I suggest that you back up /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
sudo cp /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.bak
```

Next edit the original file:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Remove these two lines entirely:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlan0
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x).

Reboot. Now can you click the Network Manager icon, see your network and connect?

Comment: Removed lines were restored after restarting system. There was no network manager icon or entry in settings for controlling the network selection.

Comment: Something other than netplan or NM is controlling here. May we see: `ls /etc`